# Market price charts in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, charts

I'm making an application in Qt to show bitcoin charts (perhaps to trade in the future as well).

I want it to be presented in the traditional OHLC (Open High Low Close) format.

So far the only ways I found to chart the price data was in Python (and not easy to update in realtime at all). Anyone knows a good chart library for C++/Qt that I can use here?

I see Qt, has Qt charts, but that's a paid library and I want my project to be free.

Comment: [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). One of its examples is a stock chart.

Answer (score 4):

The [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com) library can create OHLC and candlestick charts:

[image: QCustomPlot financial chart]

The class you're looking for there is the [QCPFinancial](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPFinancial.html#details) plottable. For realtime display, you can change all the data with `setData(...)` and access or modify existing values with the `data()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I've used QWT for live charts in biomedical applications and liked it a lot.

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

It has a trade plot class you could have a look at:

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_trading_curve.html